# Invoke powershell (Invoke-Rest) command from groovy does not return anything

Tags: powershell, groovy

I have a powershell command Invoke-RestMethod which is getting a file from Git.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = $('Bearer OTg....')} -Uri https://bitbucket.domain/repos/test/browse/base/test.txt?raw -OutFile test.txt
```

If I put that in groovy script and execute with **groovy test.groovy**:

```
["powershell", "command", "Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = 'Bearer OTg...'} -Uri https://bitbucket.domain/repos/test/browse/base/test.txt?raw -OutFile test.txt"].execute();
```

I am not getting any result or Error.
Script is executed since I add some random println lines but I do not get my file.

Can someone please help me what I am missing?
Or how this can be debugged further?

Thanks

Comment: You do not specify a full, absolute path for -OutFile.. That means PowerShell is using its current location to save the file, while groovy probably uses a different curent location. Start a PowerShell and type `$pwd`. Then look for the file there

Comment: @Theo thanks for your assistance but unfortunately this does not resolve. My home folder does not contain this file.
Also if I add full path in OutFile I still do not get file.
`-OutFile 'C:\\Users\\andrey\\test.txt` on the given path

Answer (score 1):

Try using -Command rather than command, this is fine for a simple example like:

```
["powershell", "-Command", "Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1 -OutFile test.txt"].execute();
```

But for your scenario you may need some feedback when things go wrong e.g.

```
def sout = new StringBuilder(), serr = new StringBuilder()
def args = ["powershell", "-Command", "Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = 'Bearer OTg...'} -Uri https://bitbucket.domain/repos/test/browse/base/test.txt?raw -OutFile test.txt"]
def proc = new ProcessBuilder( args )
Process process = proc.start()
process.consumeProcessOutput( sout, serr )
process.waitForOrKill( 10000 )
println serr
```